# mySQL workbench- 'SELECT * FROM table' not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I don't have much experience with mySQL but I thought I knew the basics. However, I am clearly missing something. I am using a database that has 6 tables, I can look at 5 of them with no problem. I was looking for some values and I wasn't sure which exact table it was in so I typed in my mySQL 101 level statement- 'SELECT * FROM project', received the values,  and saw that my target was not in there. So I next ran 'SELECT * FROM release' except that command does not work.

The MySQL Workbench underlines the word 'SELECT' and the tooltip message says- "select" is not valid at this position for this server version

When I attempt to run the command, I get Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax

So I tried deleting and rewriting, thinking it was some sort of bug but restarts and everything else I have tried is not helping and I have been unable to google anything relevant.

full command-

```
USE scorecarddb;
SHOW TABLES;
SELECT * FROM release;
```

but I usually just use the 1 line command run (aka I only run line 3 since I am already in the scorecard db). And I don't think it is an actual syntax error because if I change the word 'release' to 'project' or any of the other table names, it works

Comment: Please share more details

Comment: I just edited to show the full SQL commands, but it really is as simple as it sounds. I have been running only the single line that works just fine for 5 of the 6 tables.

Comment: Hmm perhaps an undocumented reserved word (I get the same error) try enclosing in backticks.

Comment: After a bit more research release IS a reserved word in mariadb but not mysql are you in fact using mariadb?

Comment: Thanks P.Salmon! I am using mysql and not mariadb but that did solve my problem. One of my spaghetti fixes was putting release in quotes which didn't work, but the backticks did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`release` might be a reserved keyword. Try using:

```
SELECT * FROM `release`;
```